# Designing a mysql database of relationships between contacts?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm trying to design a database of contacts but I also want to keep track of their relationships with other contacts whether it be family, friends, cowokers etc. I created a table for contacts and created an affiliates table that labels the type of relationship but I'm not sure if I did the design correct and I'm unsure if this would just be a normal many to many relationship or some sort of recursive relationship. I would also like to know how I would query to be able to get all the relationships to one contact and all of the relationships to all contacts.

```
Contacts Table
CID CFirstName CLastName
1   Roy        Saldana
2   Linda      Rodriguez
3   Hector     Rodriguez

Both CID & C_ID are the same I just thought I couldn't name both columns the same so I gave one a _.

Affiliates Table
CID   AfiliateType C_ID  ex: CID is the mother of C_ID 1
2     mother        1 
1     son           2 
3     husband       2 
3     step-father   1 
3     wife          3
```

```
SELECT Contacts.FirstName, Contacts.LastName, Afiliates.AfiliateType 
FROM Contacts 
INNER JOIN Afiliates 
ON Contacts.CID = Afiliates.C_ID
```

I know this isn't the correct way but I can't seem to get passed this part, I'm thinking I need to query the names twice or maybe it's a programming issue not the design, I'm totally lost. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you know something is not correct, why not fix it? Additionally, please concentrate on asking one single question at a time

Comment: Your tables look fine, except I'd name the C_ID column AffiliateCID.  You wrote a comment to keep it straight, and I was confused when typing this comment.  Generally, CID and AffiliateCID would be the primary key, so put them next to each other.  As far as your SELECT statement, you want two contacts, so you're going to have to select from the Contact table twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Contact CID is named FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME.
--
contacts {CID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME}
      PK {CID}
      AK {FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME}


-- Contact CID_1 is AFF_TYPE of contact CID_2.
--
affiliates {CID_1, CID_2, AFF_TYPE}
        PK {CID_1, CID_2}

FK1 {CID_1} REFERENCES contacts {CID}
FK2 {CID_2} REFERENCES contacts {CID}

CHECK (CID_1 <> CID_2)
```

Contact `FROM_FIRST` `FROM_LAST` is `AFF_TYPE` of `TO_FIRST` `TO_LAST`.

```sql
SELECT b.FIRST_NAME AS FROM_FIRST
     , b.LAST_NAME  AS FROM_LAST
     , a.AFF_TYPE
     , c.FIRST_NAME AS TO_FIRST
     , c.LAST_NAME  AS TO_LAST
FROM affiliates AS a
JOIN contacts   AS b ON b.cid = a.cid_1
JOIN contacts   AS c ON c.cid = a.cid_2
WHERE a.cid_1 = the_contact_id
   OR a.cid_2 = the_contact_id ;
```

One thing to consider is what to do with symmetrical relations, for example
`CID_1 is mother of CID_2`, is not symmetrical, but `CID_1 is sibling of CID_2` is.
For symmetrical relations it is the usual way to insert rows only for `CID_1 < CID_2`.

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key   (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to query the names twice. Once for the Contact and a second time for their affiliate:

```sql
    SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, a.AfiliateType, ac.FirstName AS AffiliateFirstName, ac.LastName AS AffiliateLastName
    FROM Contacts c LEFT JOIN Afiliates a ON c.CID = a.C_ID
    LEFT JOIN Contact ac ON a.CID = ac.CID
```

The key is to set up an alias for the Contacts table to use it a second time as the Affiliate Contact.

Please note, I didn't test this, so I might have made a slight error, but I hope it gives you the idea.